# Printf string with 20 characters regardless of string length C

Tags: c, string, printf

I want to print a string with exactly 20 characters regardless of whether the length of the str is shorter or longer. Right now I am using:

```
printf("%20s:",r->str);
```

This doesn't shorten the string if it is too long but it does add the padding correctly. How can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `printf` width *and* precision format modifiers for strings.

You are already familiar with the width modifier, `%Ns`, where `N` is the minimum field with to consume. The *precision* modifier (yes, syntax-similar to floating point precision modifier), establishes the maximum number of characters to consume. `%.Ms`, where `M` is the maximal number of characters to consume. And the money question, can you use both? Yes, you can: `%N.Ms`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "1234567890";
    printf("%5.5s\n", str);
}
```

**Output**

```
12345
```

Note that one/both of these can be dynamically set by using a `*` rather than a fixed width, and providing the dynamic length as a preamble argument in the `printf` argument list. An (admittedly boring) example is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "1234567890";

    for (int i=2; i<=5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=2; j<=5; ++j)
            printf("%%%d.%%%d : %*.*s\n", i, j, i, j, str);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
%2.%2 : 12
%2.%3 : 123
%2.%4 : 1234
%2.%5 : 12345
%3.%2 :  12
%3.%3 : 123
%3.%4 : 1234
%3.%5 : 12345
%4.%2 :   12
%4.%3 :  123
%4.%4 : 1234
%4.%5 : 12345
%5.%2 :    12
%5.%3 :   123
%5.%4 :  1234
%5.%5 : 12345
```